# Trouble understanding a step in simplification of equation regarding dipol moment and point charges

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-analysis

I am studying a example of an equation regaring the electric potential of a dipol in the origin. The equation is regarding a power expansion series in order to look at the limit when q goes to infinity. I'm having trouble understanding the simplification between step (3) and (4). After spending some time on it without getting anywhere I would appreciate some help.

The equation:

[image]

Comment: This is Taylor expansion of $(1+x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: I dont know how to upvote your comment but thank you, this led me in the right direction.